# error in outputting information c programming

Tags: c, output, scanf

This program works just how I want but there is only one bug. It doesn't convert from euro to dollar, it just gives me

> 0.0 euro = 0.0 dollars;

Can you guys help me please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void dollar(float dollar);

int main()
{
    char what;
    int howmany;
    int i;
    float dollar2;
    float euro2;

    printf("enter how many times do you want to convert\n");
    scanf(" %d", &howmany);
    printf("enter U if you want to convert from USD to Euro\n");
    printf("enter E if you want to convert from Euro to USD\n");

    for(i=0; i<=howmany-1; i++)
    {
        scanf(" %c", &what);
        if(what == 'E')
        {
            printf(" Enter how many euros do you want to convert\n");
            scanf(" %f", &euro2);
            euro(euro2);
        }
        if(what == 'U' ){
            printf(" Enter how many dollars do you want to convert\n");
            scanf(" %f", &dollar2);
            dollar(dollar2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void dollar(float dollar)
{
    float euro = 0.94 * dollar;
    printf("%0.2f dollar = %0.2f euro\n", dollar, euro);
    return;
}

void euro(float euro)
{
    float dollar = 1.37 * euro;
    printf("%0.2f EURO = %0.2f DOLLAR\n", euro, dollar);
    return;
}
```

Comment: i first enter 4 and then it asks for the currency so i enter E that's it

Comment: yeah it works fine for USD but not as well for Euro!

Comment: Might be a good idea to declare a prototype for the `euro` function too.

Comment: @talalalsharaa: What do you enter after E?

Comment: a digit like 1,2,3,etc...

Comment: I't worked good finally i forgot to add a prototype for euro function

Comment: @talalalsharaa you really *must* pay heed to your compiler warnings.

Comment: sorry :( @WeatherVane

Comment: @talalalsharaa are you from dara'a syria?

Comment: You are not checking the `scanf()` return value, it might be failing to `scanf()` the input because of the locale or some other problem but you don't know that, because you ignore the return value.

Comment: note: float values have a trailing 'f'.  Without the trailiing 'f' the values are doubles, so the math is being performed with double numbers and then converted to float.

Comment: The actual problem is that there is no declaration of the `euro()` function, note that it appears that `dollar()` is working well.

Comment: @user3629249 Minor point: "math is being performed with double numbers" is better stated as "math is being performed with _at least_ double numbers".  See: `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

Answer (score 1):

"In computer programming, a function prototype or function interface is a declaration of a function that specifies the function's name and type signature (arity, parameter types, and return type), but omits the function body."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype

Bascially, since euro is declared after main, when you have a call to euro in main, it has no idea where the function is. This could be avoided by declaring the function above main, or by using a function prototype.

The structure of a function prototype is like this

```
your_return_type function_name(arg_type,arg_type,arg_type....);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring `euro()` before `main()` so, when you call it in `main()` the compiler is assuming that it takes `int` as a parameter, converting your value to `0` when it's passed.

Add this

```
void euro(float value);
```

before `main()` and it will work.

But I suggest checking `scanf()`'s returned value even if it works, because it will be more robust, and you will get used to do error checking, which is a very tedious thing to do, but a very necessary thing too.